# ExtJS - Fill and Auto Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, extjs

I'm using ExtJS (html/css) and I've got a question regarding Layout. Example:

```
|--------|
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|--------|
|        |
|        |
|--------|
```

The combined height (they don't have any padding, margin etc.) is 100% of it's parent container. Preferably, it's **two panels** somehow stacked on each other.

The problem is that I **don't know the height** of neither the top panel nor the bottom panel (it's not fixed, and may change since the content within the panels may change, it's two menus.) I need the **top panel** to **fill** out the remaining space, or have a **scrollbar if needed**.

It's not that important that the solution is pure ExtJS, it's just that the container for the two panels is an ExtJS panel, the content of the two panels inside is plain html driven by javascript.

Anybody who has a clue where to start?

*Edit*
I think a part of the problem is the lack of the "resize" event. I think I can get away with some semi-dynamic/static solution and try to calculate the height of the lower panel

Comment: The first thing that pops into my mind is the `vbox` layout using the `flex` option on the top panel.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work (I've already looked into that) since the documentation says: Each child item with a flex property will be flexed vertically according to each item's relative flex value compared to the sum of all items with a flex value specified. Any child items that have either a flex = 0 or flex = undefined will not be 'flexed' (the initial size will not be changed).

Comment: Which version of Ext JS are you using?

Comment: I as using ExtJS 3 I think, but it's more then two years ago I wrote this question so I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy problem to solve. By your description of the problem Panel 2 must have `autoHeight: true`, but there is no way to tell the browser or Ext to automatically size the top panel according to that.

The best I can come up with is to do it manually on a timer:

- Create an outer container for both panels with an absolute layout, fixed height. Apply a custom "position: relative" style to it.
- Panel 1 has `config x: 0, y: 0, anchor: "100% 100%", autoScroll: true`
- Panel 2 is `autoHeight: true` with custom `style: "top: auto; bottom: 0"`
- Run a task on an interval of 1 sec or so that checks the height of Panel 2, and assigns that height to a padding-bottom style on Panel 1

Comment: Hm, seems like the solution will be something like this. (It's something like this I've implemented, but without the timer, instead I try to relayout when I think something might have happened.) Anyway, I'm accepting your answer since you've come to the same conclusion as I have :)

Answer (score 9):

There may be a easier way. In ExtJS 4 (I haven't tested in 3 but it might work) when using the **vbox** layout if a child item has a `flex` of `0` or `undefined` the layout manager will not adjust the height of that item.

So for your example, the top panel would have a `flex` of `1` and the bottom panel would have a `flex` of `0`:

```
Ext.create("widget.panel", {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  height: 300, width: 400,
  layout: { type: 'vbox', pack: 'start', align: 'stretch' },
  items: [{
    // our top panel
    xtype: 'container', 
    flex: 1,             // take remaining available vert space
    layout: 'fit', 
    autoScroll: true, 
    items: [{ 
      xtype: 'component', 
      // some long html to demonstrate scrolling
      html: '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>'
    }] 
  },{ 
    // our bottom panel
    xtype: 'container', 
    flex: 0,             // dont change height of component (i.e. let children dictate size.)
    items: [{ 
      xtype: 'button', 
      height: 200, 
      text: 'Hello World'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Now the bottom panel will just take the height of any child components and the top panel will take the remaining available height.

Answer (score 3):

If I get the question correct- the two panels should not have a fixed size UNLESS they have content, in which case they scroll? Typically I would suggest that at least one of the panels represents 'master' content and has a fixed size. Otherwise, this should work:

```
layout:'vbox',
layoutConfig: {
    align : 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start',
},
items: [
    {html:'panel 1', flex:1},
    {html:'panel 2', flex:2}
]
```

Simply give that config to the 'holding' element and then setup 'panel 1' and 'panel 2' as you see fit (i.e. replace '{html:'panel 1', flex:1}' with the name of the component)

Comment: I can't have neither the first, nor the second one to be fixed. (I might get away with the second one to be fixed as a temporary solution, though.) However, this will allow the first one to use whatever space there's left, and the second one to use whatever space it needs..? (I interpret the flex as panel 1 will get 33% and panel 2 will get 67% of the space?)

Comment: There is a bit of a logic question here, 'the second one to use whatever space it needs.' could potentially mean panel 1 is completely minimised/squashed- so surely you want to fix a max height for panel 2 to prevent this?

Comment: Probably, but that's not the big problem right now. (However, in case it matters to the solution, I would probably prefer if they both get what they want, and then the container for them both will add a scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a CSS trick ('max-height' CSS field) instead of 'layout' and 'flex' ExtJS fields. For that just add the following lines to element which should be scrollable:

```
bodyStyle: { maxHeight: '300px' },
autoScroll: true,
```

Tested with ExtJS 3.4.0.